# Facades: Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am created a class and Facade like so:

Invoice.php (Facades/Invoice.php)

```
<?php

namespace app\Facades\;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Invoice extends Facade
{
   protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
   {
        //NEVER CALLED
        dd("TEST");

        return 'invoice';
    }
}
?>
```

InvoiceFacadesServiceProviders.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class InvoiceFacadesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   public function boot()
   {
      //
   }
   public function register()
   {
      App::bind('invoice',function()
      {
         return new \App\Invoice\Invoice;
      });
   }
}
?>
```

And finally the class itself:

```
<?php


namespace App\Invoice;

class Invoice
{
    public function testfunc()
    {
        return "This is a test";
    }
}
?>
```

In a controller I try to test it by using the class like so:

```
use App\Invoice\Invoice;
```

And calling the testfunc method:

```
dd(Invoice::testfunc());
```

In the `app.php` I have added the following (providers):         `App\Providers\InvoiceFacadesServiceProvider::class,`
and (aliases):         `'invoice' => App\Facades\Invoice::class,`

But I only get:

```
Non-static method App\Invoice\Invoice::testfunc() should not be called statically.
```

I also notice that the `getFacadeAccessor()` method never gets fired since it does not hit the `dd` I have put there.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help and guidance!

Comment: remove static from that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call the class `Invoice`, not the Facace `Invoice`. And that's why the warning occurs.

Try to call `\App\Facades\Invoice::testfunc();`, then you call the method through facade.